# How to get a list of installed applications on the system using node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I wanted to create a similar workflow like that of windows where they give suggestions to open an application using a program installed on the system, listing all the possible applications that can open a file. Is there an API for it in node js?

Comment: Does the Node application run on the computer where you want the installed applications to be observed or are you running the app in a server and view in a browser?

Comment: Please Refer about `child process` https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: @HerrSerker  it runs on the computer.

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar child_process would let me exec the process once I get the application .exe path, the problem is, I don't have the path to .exe, that is what I need from the List of installed apps on the desktop.

Comment: @SudhanshuMonga you can execute `wmic` commands in CMD using child_process

Answer (score 0):

Import `child process`

Then execute,
`wmic /output:E:\InstallList.txt product get name,version` command in child_process,

Once you execute the command, You can find a list of installed program in `E:\InstallList.txt`. Read this file with `nodeJS` to get result.

**You can customize the output file path**

Comment: is there a way to get a list on the basis of the file extension that can be given, ex: for .png format just show apps that can open .png format.

Comment: I think, The answer is NO